# How do I make this ripped paper/vintage effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, effects, photography

[image]

I am using photoshop.

I have tried by following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxbC5HKnT3o

But it doesn't seem to have the vintage/realistic touch to it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That is one awful tutorial.

Anyhow, print your graphic on a piece of paper, rip said paper, photograph or scan it. This will give the best result as far as the edge goes.

Alternatively, rip any piece of of paper, photograph it, use it as clipping masks and texture for your artwork. You'll want to offset the clipping mask from the edge so it has a better torn look, which again is why the first option is better.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the effect like in picture shown:

1. Have some picture already in photoshop
2. Find ripped paper image you want to use and drag it to PS
3. Make selection of paper using selection tools (to make mask in next steps)
4. Keep the selection while selecting picture layer in the layers panel
5. Click mask button below layers. The mask will create on picture layer.
6. Double click on picture layer to open - layer effects panel
7. Add stroke - color white, adjust other properties visually
8. Add Drop shadow effect, make it barely visible

You will get the same effect as it is in picture above.
Optional: Improvise using Bevel in the layer effects panel

Sorry, can't take screenshot from phone to make it easier for you.